# GCP pub/sub equivalent in AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there pub/sub equivalent in AWS where message is published from region A and and Lambda deployed in Region B and Region C gets triggered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is GCP pub/sub region specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65053230/is-gcp-pub-sub-region-specific)

Comment: No, that's a different question.